# How to change device name in Profile Manager

Tags: profile-manager, configuration-profiles, mdm

I run Maverick 10.9 Mac mini server. After enroll some new devices into Profile Manager I need to change their name. I can't find any field that could change the device name. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can only change it if your devices are enrolled in supervised mode. use apple configurator 2 to enroll the device to MDM, then you can select the supervised mode option.

after it's successfully enrolled, you can then rename the devices via the profile manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Profile Manager to change the name of a device, the device name is one of the keys.

Comment: Hi Tony,
Is there a way to change it from the server? Thank you